# The shortest path that meets every extended line that passes through a circle of radius $r$

Tags: geometry, circles

Problem: 
A straight underground pipe passes by a statue at a maximum distance of 100 meters. The exact whereabouts of this pipe is unknown. What is the shortest trench i must dig that will assure me to find the arbitrary laid pipe.

The answer appears to be a half circle with two lines of length 100 m aranged like a horse shoe magnet. 
If this is the shortest trench path how could such be proven formally. e.g disproving all other trench paths.

[the bold line represent the shortest trench path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnRZA.png)

is it worth investigating this problem for IB MATHS HL INTERNAL ASSESMENT?

Comment: The way this question is phrased does not seem accurate. A chord is a line segment.

Comment: For future searchers: this is the problem of finding shortest beam detectors. https://web.archive.org/web/19961110073734/http://www.mathsoft.com/asolve/constant/beam/beam.html

Answer (score -1):

Without typo, length is equal to $ 2 r + \pi r.$

Comment: The question is about proving that this is the shortest path, not about calculating its length.